# Changing Account Balance in TradingView Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I would like to simulate deposits or withdrawals to my account within a strategy. Unfortunately, it looks like trying to do something like

`strategy.initial_capital = 5000`

nor

`strategy.equity = 5000`

work. I couldn't find any information on how to try and do this in the [Strategies documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html), but would like to ask the community if they know if this is possible (or even if a 'hack' for simulating deposits or withdrawals from an account is possible).

Any assistance with this is appreciated! I think it could be super valuable to simulate withdrawals and deposits to an account within TradingView.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TradingView's Pine Script does not support simulating deposits or withdrawals directly within a strategy. The `strategy.initial_capital` and `strategy.equity` properties are read-only and cannot be modified during the script execution.

However, you can use a workaround to simulate the effect of deposits or withdrawals on your position sizing. You can create a custom function to adjust the position size based on the simulated account balance. Here's an example:

```
deposit_amount = input(1000, "Deposit Amount", type=input.integer)
deposit_interval = input(5, "Deposit Interval", type=input.integer)

posSize() =>
    float deposit = na
    if (bar_index % deposit_interval == 0)
        deposit := deposit_amount
    else
        deposit := 0
    deposit

var float account_balance = na
if (na(account_balance))
    account_balance := strategy.initial_capital
else
    account_balance := account_balance + posSize()

if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=account_balance / close)
if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=account_balance / close)
```

In this example, the script simulates a deposit of a specified amount every specified interval of bars. The position size is adjusted based on the simulated account balance.